# Parse Array into Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array called $userLineArray within that array I would like to parse each entry by space.  Then I would like to echo that into a new multidimensional array called $userLineArray2

```
         foreach ($userLineArray as $key => $value) {
            $keywords1 = preg_split("/[\s,\t]+/", $value);
            array_replace($userLineArray2, array($key => $keywords1));
        }
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: What do you expect array_replace to do? I'm not sure if you want to replace userLineArray2 each time or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just:

```
foreach ($userLineArray as $key => $value) {
    $keywords1 = preg_split("/[\s,\t]+/", $value);
    $userLineArray2[$key] = $keywords1;
}
```

[Test Code here](http://rextester.com/live/IFF7484). Presumably this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Please avoid posting a presumed code-only answer to an unclear question.  This does not benefit Stack Overflow.